# Place image and table side by side

Tags: tables, graphics

I'm trying to place an image and a table side by side.
Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\label{my-label1}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{IIIT} & {\bf Shubham Rathi}           & {\bf Male}          \\
                      & {\bf Computer Science}   & {\bf B. Tech + MS (Computational Humanities)}           \\
                      & {\bf IIIT Hyderabad} & {\bf}     
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This is causing my image to be skewed upwards from the table:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

What should I be doing?

The Sharelatex file is here: www.sharelatex.com/project/57e542d03afea89017192474

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need in your case is `\multirow`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\label{my-label1}

\bfseries

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=0.8in]{IIIT}}
        &                     &       \\
        &  Shubham Rathi      &  Male                                    \\
        &  Computer Science   &  B. Tech + MS (Computational Humanities) \\
        &  IIIT Hyderabad     &      \\
        &                     &
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The table and the image are still not aligned center wrt to each other and the columns are not having a margin. Please see here:
https://www.sharelatex.com/project/57e542d03afea89017192474

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect! So the solution was to add a padding of one row above to shift the table content below?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{IIIT}}
```

should do the trick, if there is nothing else in the same column.

Comment: Its displacing it below: http://prnt.sc/cm81bo